Is there a compact form of $\frac{2}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin^2(\pi jk/(n+1))}{z-2\cos(\pi k/(n+1))}$ in terms of $z$, $n$, $j$?
I would like to evaluate the following sum:
$$S_j(z,n)=\frac{2}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  j k}{n+1}\right)}{z-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n+1}\right)}$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is an arbitrary constant with ${\rm Im}(z)\neq 0$ and $j=1,2,3,\dots,n$.
My first attempt was to expand the terms of the sum as a Fourier series, but the calculations become very quickly long and tedious. Is there any simple way to evaluate this sum?
(What I mean with evaluate is that I get a compact expression in terms of $z$, $n$ and $j$.)
Edit: Almost there...
Let
$$F(x)=\frac{\sin ^2\left(jx\right)}{z-2 \cos \left(x\right)}$$
with fixed $j$ and $z$. We first expand $F(x)$ as a Fourier series:
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m \cos (m x).$$
(The $\sin$ coefficients are all zero). Now, using routine complex analysis, we obtain:
$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(x)\mathrm{d}x =\frac{2 - \left( \frac{z - \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{-2j} - 2 \left( \frac{z - \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{2j} + \left( \frac{z + \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{2j}}{2 \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}$$
If $m>2j$:
$$a_m=- \frac{\left( \frac{z - \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{-2j + m} \left(1 - \left( \frac{z - \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{2j} \right)^2}{2 \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}$$
If $m\leq 2j$:
$$a_m=- \left( \frac{\left( \frac{z - \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{-2j + m} \left(1 - \left( \frac{z - \sqrt{-4 + z^2}}{2} \right)^{2j} \right)^2}{2 \sqrt{-4 + z^2}} + \frac{- \left( \frac{z + \sqrt{z^2 - 4}}{2} \right)^{2j - m} + \left( \frac{z - \sqrt{z^2 - 4}}{2} \right)^{2j - m}}{2 \sqrt{z^2 - 4}} \right)$$
$$S_j(z,n)=\frac{2n}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  j k}{n+1}\right)}{z-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n+1}\right)}$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}=a_0$, if I am not mistaken (?) I can express $S_j(z,n)$ as:
$$S_j(z,n)-a_0=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(m nx)F(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
but this last formula is wrong. I am almost there! any hints?

You can add your attempt with Fourier series.

It is very unlikely that such an expression has a closed form for its partial sums. To see this, consider the much more simple expression:  $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)$. I know absolutely no closed form for the partial sum (even its exponential form has poor algebraic flexibility, since most terms end up being linearly independent within the real numbers)

@SimónFlavioIbañez Doesn't your 'simpler' expression fall immediately to a combination of exponential form and then summing the partial geometric series? $\sum_k\cos(kx)$ $=\frac12\sum_k(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})$ $=\frac12\left(\sum_k(e^{ix})^k+\sum_k(e^{-ix})^k\right)$ $=\ldots$

@StevenStadnicki i don't know in which way my expression isn't simpler than the original one... But anyways: yes, a geometric series can evaluate the expression correctly, but will only yield true values if |$e^{ix}|<1\wedge |e^{-ix}|<1$, which is clearly not the case, since $|e^{±ix}|=e^{ix}e^{-ix}=1$ for any complex number $x$. Particularly, for $x=j=1,2,3...n$, these series aren't defined.

A possible approach is to use the series (here $|z|<1$)
$$
\frac{1-z^2}{1-2z\cos\phi+z^2}=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}z^{|m|}\cos m\phi.
$$
The given sum equals $F_1(n+1,j,z)$, where
$$
F_1(n,j,z)=\frac2n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sin^2\frac{\pi jk}n}{z-2\cos\frac{\pi k}n}=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{\sin^2\frac{\pi jk}n}{z-2\cos\frac{\pi k}n}
$$
(the summand is invariant under $k\mapsto 2n-k$).
Write $F_1(n,j,z)=F_2(2n,2j,z)$, where
$$
F_2(n,j,z)=\frac2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\sin^2\frac{\pi jk}n}{z-2\cos\frac{2\pi k}n}.
$$
Write $F_2(n,j,z)=F_3(n,0,z)-F_3(n,j,z)$, where
$$
F_3(n,j,z)=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\cos\frac{2\pi jk}n}{z-2\cos\frac{2\pi k}n}.
$$
Write $\displaystyle F_3\left(n,j,z+\frac1z\right)=\frac{z}{1-z^2}F_4(n,j,z)$, where
$$
F_4(n,j,z)=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1-z^2}{1-2z\cos\frac{2\pi k}n+z^2}\cos\frac{2\pi jk}n.
$$
Now let $|z|<1$ (temporarily) and $0\leqslant j\leqslant n$ (w.l.o.g.). Then
\begin{align*}
F_4(n,j,z)&=\frac1n\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}z^{|m|}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2\pi jk}n\cos\frac{2\pi mk}n
\\&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}z^{|m|}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\underbrace{\left(\cos\frac{2\pi k(m+j)}n+\cos\frac{2\pi k(m-j)}n\right)}_{\text{symmetry w.r.t. }m\ \mapsto\ -m}
\\&=\frac1n\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}z^{|m|}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2\pi k(m-j)}n}_{\text{vanishes if }n\ \not\mid\ m-j}
=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}z^{|j+mn|}=\color{blue}{\frac{z^j+z^{n-j}}{1-z^n}.}
\end{align*}
By analytic continuation, the condition $|z|<1$ can be dropped.
It remains to substitute everything back.

When I test numerically your definition of $F_4(n,j,z)$ for $n=3,j=1,z=(1+\mathrm{i})/4$ I obtain $-\frac{128}{257}+\frac{8 i}{257}$ but the blue expression evaluates to $\frac{126}{545}+\frac{202 i}{545}$ so there seems to be a mistake somewhere

@papad: I get the second value ($\frac{126}{545}+\frac{202i}{545}$) in both cases.

My mistake. There is a small typo in the equality between $F_3$ and $F_4$, you need to rescale $z\toz/2$ in order to get the correct expression for $F_3$. Other than that your method actually gives the correct expression!
